# What are the uses of typescript JSON files

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am new in typescript and I am trying to learn ts. I have one small clarification
what is the use and functionality of following the json files in typeascript.

```
1.tsconfig.json
2.task.json
3.launch.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [conf/typescript](https://github.com/troxler/conf/blob/master/conf/typescript.md) for a list of TypeScript configuration files. Only [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) is actually related to TypeScript. `task.json` and `launch.json` are both used for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thank you so much.